# Chrome downloading index.php file but not other .php files

Tags: php, google-chrome, wamp

I am currently having a problem with my WAMP/Google Chrome. On my wamp server (running on windows) I have enabled the use of the httpd-vhosts.conf file and modified my HOSTS file to accept different "server" names ie. `127.0.0.1 mysite` and set my vhosts file to say:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/Documents/Websites/mysite"
    ServerName mysite
    ErrorLog "logs/your_own-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/your_own-access.log" common
    <directory "D:/Documents/Websites/mysite">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine when I'm viewing pages such as **about.php**, **contact.php** but when I try to view the **index.php** file, chrome downloads the file (it does the same in rockmelt - I assume since they both based on chrome). It works fine in firefox, opera, safari and IE9 so its not the actual php file itself (also if I rename **index.php** to anything else it works fine in chrome).

I have even changed the content of the index.php file to simply do:

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

But Chrome still downloads the file.

Thanks

Comment: When chrome downloads the file, what is inside? The source or generated text "test"?

Comment: The file contains the actual source code. I have multiple projects set up under wamp, and it doesn't do this on any of the other projects. And I have checked, and this project is set up exactly the same as the others.

Comment: so strange, might not be because of the http header sent to browser cause firefox,ie,opera shows the index.php well...; so maybe your chrome has problem, try reinstalling chrome may solve this problem?

Comment: I considered that it might be chrome, but then it would affect all my projects, not just this one. And the same problem occurs in Rockmelt.

Comment: I think this must be something with your server setting. If setup correctly all request to this file should return the generated text not the source no matter who does the request or what the request headers are.

Comment: I thought about that too... Although If it was a server setting wouldn't that affect every browser? And not just chrome?

Comment: If you are getting the actual PHP source code in this "download", then it has **nothing** to do with the client, and everything to do with your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange, and while I think this is a server issue, it *might* be caused by some weird extensions. Try with all your extensions disabled and see if you still have the problem.

If you still have the problem, it can be an Apache configuration issue.

Comment: Ok, well I disabled all my Chrome extensions and it still downloads the index.php file, so its not the extensions.

Comment: Then the problem is a server configuration issue. Is there an `.htaccess` file in the `index.php` directory? Can you post a minimal but complete non-working apache config file?